# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I received a syntax error message

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag 'e_date', I18n.l( Date.today , :format=>:default),:year_range     => 15.years.ago..5.years.from_now, :readonly=>true, :popup=>"force",
{:onchange => "#{remote_function(
  :url => { :action => 'report_new' },
  :with => "'start_date='+s_date+'end_date='+e_date+'&batch_id='+#{@batch.id}",
  :before => "Element.show('loader')",
  :success => "Element.hide('loader')"  )}" }%>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'})
```

**or**

Dont mix your view/html with javascript(forget obstrusive javascript)
instead,there is one more cleaner way....

```
    <%= select_tag :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name), :onchange => 'your_onchange_handler()' %>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    function your_onchange_handler(){
    //do what u want to do when select changes    
    }

})//document ready ends



</script>
```